# Laravel Sail - Migration are working but can't register new user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker-compose, laravel-sail

I've set up a new laravel project and here's the step I followed :

- install laravel on docker using

  ```
   curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash
  ```
- changing mysql port as 3306 is already used in my machine. Files have changed

***.env file***

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=0.0.0.0
DB_PORT=4306
DB_DATABASE=example_app
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

***docker-compose file (mysql container section)***

```
mysql:
    image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-4306}:3306'
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
        MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
        MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
    volumes:
        - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
    networks:
        - sail
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
        retries: 3
        timeout: 5s
```

- build and run container

  ./vendor/bin/sail up
- run 1st migration

Everything works fine at this point.

Then I install [breeze](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/breeze) package and run the migration

```
composer require laravel/breeze && php artisan migrate
```

**Everything is still working at this point.**

Then when I try to register a new user entering the adress ***localhost/register***, I get the following error

```
lluminate \ Database \ QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = my_new_user@test.com
```

Am I missing something in the .env or the docker-compose.yml ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm using sail with breeze as well only differences is my docker compose port line is `- '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'` and my .env host and port are `DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306`

Comment: im not sure it's related with the port, but i've tried bringing back to 3306, rebuild the containers but still..

Comment: connection refused means your application is failed to connect with database with given port. it might be blocked or protected by firewall rule

Comment: I understand that, but the thing is that the migration worked but not the creation of user... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix by changing the environment variable with the Gateway IP

Use this command to find this IP

```
docker network inspect bridge
```

you should have a result like the following :

```
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "17da7215587ae714f631d213fed173550b69d38a5824c1998e1c3cd4b2e954b",
        "Created": "2022-10-26T19:26:38.585884296Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

use the Gateway entry in your .env file